# Account Lookup while Adding Contact overrides Address

Tags: contact, bug

### Description

On the Contact object, the Account field is a lookup.

As such, when adding a new contact to Salesforce, there are 3 ways to fill the Account field with data:

1. Click the search button, and find an existing Account within Salesforce.

   - In this case, **the Address listed on the Account is copied to the Contact**--this copying will override any Address information previously typed in on the Contact (even if the Account's address is blank).
2. Type all or part of the name of an existing Account.

   - In this case, when the Contact is Saved, the Account field will be filled in with the targeted Account; however, **the Address will not be copied from the Account to the Contact**.
3. Type part of the name of more than one account.

   Example: type "a" when both "ABC Company" and "A to Z Company" exist in Salesforce.

   - In this case, when the Contact is saved, an Error will occur, and a picklist will be displayed with all potential matching Accounts. Upon selecting an Account and saving again, the Account will be filled, but **the Address will not be copied over to the Contact**.

---

### Satisfaction

In order to fix this, the Account Address should be copied to the Contact regardless of how the Account field is filled.

---

### Question

Is this a known bug? Can you reproduce it? Is there a simple fix or does this need to be reported through an official channel?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a workflow that populates the Contact mailing address fields with data from the Account billing address.

[image: Here's the workflow I created in our org]

[image: And the workflow actions...]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is by design. [See Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqW4AAK) for suggestions on changing.

In use case 1 - the lookup echoes back the address info to give you the chance to override it

In use case 2 - the Save happens without any user interaction. SFDC assumes you entered the address detail on the Contact prior to hitting Save - they are entry fields so if you leave them blank, SFDC thinks you want the Contact to be without mailing address.

Use case 3 is a variant of #2

I agree that it can seem counterintuitive.

In an Account with folks working at multiple locations, each Contact for an Account could have a different address than the headquarters address represented by the Account record

Often, to avoid the situation you have, one would start at the Account page and click the New Contact button from the Contacts related list - this will pre-associate the Contact to the parent Account and the Contact's address will default as expected.

@Brittany's answer is one workaround if you have this convention although I might modify it to execute only when the mailing address in the Contact is blank